# customizable blog feed sharepoint 2010 web part

Tags: sharepoint, blogs, web-parts

I work in IT for a community college and we need a SharePoint 2010 solution that is, essentially, a blog in which the different departments can make announcements through posts and the individual user can "subscribe" to the different departments in order to receive the announcements that they want to see, but not the ones they don't.  The subscribed to posts should be displayed in a web part that they see on their SharePoint home screen.  The needs of this are as follows:

- Posting is restricted to certain users only
- Categories or tags used to identify which department the post originates from must be rigidly definable.
- Web part displays only those posts user is subscribed to.
- Setting up/editing a user's subscriptions must be as painless as possible, we're dealing with a lot of technophobic users here.

Beyond that, we're pretty flexible.  I imagine the blog that comes with SharePoint would be fine, it's the web part aspect of this that's stymied us.  Is something like this possible within SharePoint 2010 or is there a third party app that anyone has heard of that might provide this functionality?  We've been searching for ages and have come up with nothing.

Thanks very much for your time!

Marcus Vowell